# Basic question about longtabu

Tags: tabu, longtabu

I'm very new to `longtabu` and LaTeX, so I found an example of a table and have a question.

What exactly is the meaning of the characters `l` and `p` in this line of code?

```
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1,l,p] X[0.25,l,p]  X[0.25,l,p]  X[0.25,l,p]  X[0.25,l,p]  X[0.25,l,p] }
```

What other parameters can be there?

Here is all the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

{\small \begin{center}
\tabulinesep=2mm
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1,l,p] X[0.25,l,p]  X[0.25,l,p]  X[0.25,l,p]  X[0.25,l,p]  X[0.25,l,p] }  % {|X|X|X|}
\hline \hline 
\textbf{Описание корректирующих мероприятий} & \textbf{Место проведения мероприятия} & \textbf{Ответственный за проведение мероприятия}  & \textbf{Плановая дата реализации} & \textbf{Фактическая дата реализации}  & \textbf{Статус реализации}   \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endfoot
\caption{Table title 2.}
\endlastfoot
Нарисовать красную линию на полу, как границу для установки товара & Склад №11, зона холодильника & Петров И.И. & 31.08.2015 & 30.08.2015 & Выполнено, ожидает проверки \\ \hline
Нарисовать красную линию на полу, как границу для установки товара & Склад №11, зона холодильника & Петров И.И. & 31.08.2015 & 30.08.2015 & Выполнено, ожидает проверки \\ \hline

\end{longtabu}
\end{center}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual of `tabu`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tabu/tabu.pdf) can be handy for this case. It is sitting right there in page number 3. Here is a screen shot for you:

[image]

These are the parameters a `X` type column can take inside a `tabu`.